# dictionary key-call

Tags: python, eclipse, dictionary, pydev

im building a test program. its essentially a database of bugs and bug fixes. it may end up being an entire database for all my time working in python.
i want to create an effect of layers by using a dictionary.

here is the code as of april 29 2011:

```
modules=['pass']
syntax={'PRINT':''' in eclipse anthing which 
you "PRINT" needs to be within a set of paranthesis''','StrRet':'anytime you need to use the return action in a string, you must use the triple quotes.'}

findinp= input('''where would you like to go?
Dir:''')
if findinp=='syntax':
    print(syntax)
    dir2= input('choose a listing')
    if dir2=='print'or'PRINT'or'Print':
        print('PRINT' in syntax)
```

now when i use this i get the ENTIRE dictionary, not just the first layer. how would i do something like this? do i need to just list links in the console? or is there a better way to do so?

thanks,
Pre.Shu.

Comment: Format your source code properly!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you want, but to print the content of a single key of dictionary you index it:

```
syntax['PRINT']
```

Maybe this help a bit:

```
modules=['pass']
syntax={
    'PRINT':''' in eclipse anthing which 
you "PRINT" needs to be within a set of paranthesis''',
    'STRRET':'anytime you need to use the return action in a string, you must use the triple quotes.'}

choice = input('''where would you like to go?
Dir:''').upper()

if choice in syntax:
    print syntax[choice]
else:
    print "no data ..."
```

Comment: in the oupt put i AM getting:

where would you like to go?
Dir:syntax
{'PRINT': ' in eclipse anthing which \nyou "PRINT" needs to be within a set of paranthesis', 'StrRet': 'anytime you need to use the return action in a string, y
ou must use the triple quotes.'}
choose a listing

i want to get:

where would you like to go?
Dir:syntax

syntax contains: PRINT and StrRet
Dir:Print

' in eclipse anthing which \nyou "PRINT" needs to be within a set of paranthesis'

Anything else?
Yes or No:yes
*program closes*